# Text align around symbol using tabular

Tags: tables, align

I want to align the word "vejledere" in the center between the & symbols.

[image: Table doesn't align the way i want it to]

I have the following code for the table:

```
   \begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{rcl}
   Matematik A    & \& & Informatik C \\
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Vejledere:}      \\
   Thomas Nygaard & \& & Esben Øvland
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}
```

How would i center the word in the second row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{rcl}
   Matematik A & \& & Informatik C \\
    & \makebox[0pt]{Vejledere:} \\
   Thomas Nygaard & \& & Esben Øvland
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot, last piece that annoyed me like crazy about my front page

Comment: @MagnusThomsen: B.t.w., if per chance you load  `mathtools`,  you can replace the `makebox[0pt]` command by the shorter `\clap`.

Comment: Always all the best. Nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano!

Answer (score 1):

Not a very straightforward solution, but works--

[image: Vejledere]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\V}{%
    \tikz[overlay]
      \node[yshift=0.5ex] 
        {Vejledere};
               }

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{tabular}{rcl}
   Matematik A    & \& & Informatik C \\
                  & \V &              \\
   Thomas Nygaard & \& & Esben \O{}vland
   \end{tabular}
   \end{table} 
\end{document}
```